# Scrapy Shell Splash doesn't render correctly

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, scrapy-shell

I try to render javascript page with splash in scrapy shell. I want to render Google's search result with:
scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www.google.com.tr/#q=christian+omlin+email&timeout=10&wait=0.5'

but shell return "www.google.com", not with question parameters( christian omlin email ), it just remove them.

I looked google has https, maybe 8050 not work for it, or quotes for url is wrong. Why it is happen ?

Comment: The `url` parameter should be URL-encoded. Does it change anything if you do? ie. use `url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.tr%2F%23q%3Dchristian%2Bomlin%2Bemail`

Comment: yes, it worked thank you very much :))